# Why does a view function cost gas?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm building an NFT marketplace. I have a `view` function that returns the NFTs of a user. However, this function requires a transaction and costs gas that the user must pay.

Here is the related part of the MarketContract code:

```
contract Market is ReentrancyGuard {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _listingCount;

    mapping(uint256 => Listing) public marketListings;

    struct Listing {
        uint256 listingId;
        address nftContractAdd;
        uint256 tokenId;
        address ownerAdd;
        uint256 price;
    }

    function getItemsOf (address wallet) public view returns (Listing[] memory) {
        uint resultCount = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _listingCount.current(); i++) {
            if (marketListings[i].ownerAdd == address(wallet)) {
                resultCount++; 
            }
        }

        uint itemCount = 0;
        Listing[] memory items = new Listing[](resultCount);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i <= _listingCount.current(); i++) { 
            if(marketListings[i].ownerAdd == address(wallet)) {
                items[itemCount] = marketListings[i];
                itemCount++;
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

And, here is my frontend code:

```
async getListedItemsOfUser({ }, payload) {
        const { walletAddress } = payload

        const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
        const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();

        const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(
            Secrets.MARKET_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
            MarketContract.abi,
            signer
        );

        try {
            const res = await marketContract.getListedItemsOf(walletAddress);
            console.log("listed items", res)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

### Why does this function cost gas?

Here the ABI of all the contract code: [GIST](https://gist.github.com/anileates/74ff884b3a9f0bd5cff9e7559ff90f95)

Comment: How are you measuring the gas cost? If called off-chain it shouldn't charge anything.

Comment: I couldn't get what you mean by 'measuring'? When the frontend method works, Metamask opens and the user must confirm a transaction and pay some gas. But this is only a view function? @Ismael

Comment: It shouldn't ask for confirmation. What's the abi you are using? Can you attach it to the question? For some reason the frontend code creates a transaction, and it shouldn't do it for view functions.

Comment: Here is the abi: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anileates/74ff884b3a9f0bd5cff9e7559ff90f95) @Ismael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `getListedItemsOf` method from your frontend. Shouldn't you be calling `getItemsOf` like you have posted in your question?

These two methdos have different `stateMutability` in the provided ABI.

Comment: Oh, you are right! didn't notice that. Thank you so much!